# Swift get today's number of weeks in this month

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I want to get what number or weeks by certain date in a month.

For example, If the date is 2022/11/30, I want to get the number of week in this month as 5th.

If the date is 2022/12/01, the answer should be 1st.

I want to get the answer by logical function, but It's hard to make with my skills.

Can anybody solve this problem? Thanks

I know the Date() and Calendar(), but doesn't know how to use for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateString = "2022/12/01"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone  =  .gmt
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let weekOfMonth = calendar.component(.weekOfMonth, from: date!)
print(weekOfMonth) // -> 1
```

fyi -> change the timezone value if u need

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what Im looking for.